# Embed Python code in Verilog file in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, verilog, org-mode

I am working on a project whereby I need to embed Python within a Verilog file. The Python isn't really intended for execution in the normal sense as it will be read by a secondary tool. The Python will be written blocks that have some fixed demarcation (such as #+BEGIN_SRC, in org-babel).

```
module name ();

#+BEGIN_SRC python
def my_function ():
    ...
#+END_SRC

always @(posedge clk)
    ...
endmodule
```

Within Emacs this causes havoc, although Python-mode and Verilog-mode work fine, when combining both in the same file things quickly break-down as one would expect. Indentation is hopelessly broken as is syntax-highlighting. I understand this is a very weird thing to do, and I understand that there will almost certainly never been any real need to do this under normal circumstances, however for this particular case it is necessary.

My question: is there anyway within Emacs to specify multiple major modes within the same file. For example, is there some way that I can write a file using Verilog-mode as my major mode, but use Python-mode within the predefined blocks that are then ignored in the reset of the file.

Comment: You are correct, however in this case it is not important that I obey the Verilog syntax because the tool I am creating shall strip such constructs from the final generated Verilog.

Comment: @StephenHenry, I think the suggestion was that if you *do* use valid Verilog syntax, Emacs won't be confused anymore. Of course, you won't get any kind of Python-specific functionality for those blocks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities listed here:

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes

I've used multi-mode with latex and haskell, and it works OK.

Comment: Thanks! Using your suggestion I found polymode seem appears to fit my needs.